# Ordering Merged data frames

Tags: r

As a fairly new R programmer I seem to have run into a strange problem - probably my inexperience with R

After reading and merging successive files into a single data frame, I find that order does not sort the data as expected.

I have multiple references in each file but each file refers to measurement data obtained at a different time.

Here's the code

```
library(reshape)
# Enter file name to Read & Save data
FileName=readline("Enter File name:\n")
# Find first occurance of file
for ( round1 in 1 : 6) {
ReadFile=paste(round1,"C_",FileName,"_Stats.csv", sep="")
if (file.exists(ReadFile))
break
}

x = data.frame(read.csv(ReadFile, header=TRUE),rnd=round1)
for ( round2 in (round1+1) : 6) {
#
ReadFile=paste(round2,"C_",FileName,"_Stats.csv", sep="")
if (file.exists(ReadFile)) {
y = data.frame(read.csv(ReadFile, header=TRUE),rnd = round2)
    if (round2 == (round1 +1))
    z=data.frame(merge(x,y,all=TRUE))
    z=data.frame(merge(y,z,all=TRUE))
}
}
ordered = order(z$lab_id)

results = z[ordered,]

res = data.frame( lab=results[,"lab_id"],bw=results[,"ZBW"],wi=results[,"ZWI"],pf_zbw=0,pf_zwi=0,r = results[,"rnd"])


#
# Establish no of samples recorded
nsmpls = length(res[,c("lab")])

# Evaluate Z_scores for Between Lab Results
for ( i in 1 : nsmpls) {
if (res[i,"bw"] > 3 | res[i,"bw"] < -3)
res[i,"pf_zbw"]=1
}
# Evaluate Z_scores for Within Lab Results
for ( i in 1 : nsmpls) {
if (res[i,"wi"] > 3 | res[i,"wi"] < -3)
res[i,"pf_zwi"]=1
}

dd = melt(res, id=c("lab","r"), "pf_zbw")
b = cast(dd, lab ~ r)
```

If anyone could see why the ordering only works for about 55 of 70 records and could steer me in the right direction I would be obliged

Thanks very much

Comment: Check whether z$lab_id is a factor (with is.factor(z$lab_id)). If it is, try z$lab_id <- as.character(z$lab_id) if it is supposed to be a character vector; z$lab_id <- as.numeric(as.character(z$lab_id)) if it is supposed to be a numeric vector. Then order it again.

Comment: Dear Eduardo

Thanks. Well spotted!!! I knew it was somethimg simple, just couldn't figure it out.

Yes the field lab_id is a character vector but has numbers in it.

Jonathan, thanks for the advice.

All the best
Steve

Comment: Whoops!!

After solving that problem, I now see that my 'melt' and 'cast' don't order the data correctly.

I would have thought that once results and res were correctly ordered it would automatically follow that when melting and casting it would remain ordered.

Not so. Is there someway to ensure that the melting and/ or cast treats the lab as a character vector because performing an order on  'b' doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Red face!!!!!!!!!

I solved the problem. Found that if all I had to do was order the 'cast' fram b properly and all is ok.

Sorry for the trouble.

Thanks once again

Comment: can you close this question somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether z$lab_id is a factor (with `is.factor(z$lab_id)`).

If it is, try

```
z$lab_id <- as.character(z$lab_id)
```

if it is supposed to be a character vector; or

```
z$lab_id <-    as.numeric(as.character(z$lab_id))
```

if it is supposed to be a numeric vector.

Then order it again.

Ps. I had previously put these in the comments.