# R combine data frame by two variables

Tags: r

I have two data sets, one with X and Y data, one with X Y and Z data. I wish to subset the X, Y, Z data keeping only lines which match a line from both X and Y of the first set.

Example:

```
X  Y            
1  1            
1  4            
2  7


X  Y  Z               
1  1 24                 
1  2 30  
1  4 15   
2  2 40    
2  5 10    
2  7 12
```

I want to combine these to return only:

```
X  Y  Z    
1  1 24    
1  4 15    
2  7 12
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are LOTS of answers to this question here already that could easily be found (e.g. [Ordering Merged data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041120/ordering-merged-data-frames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?merge`:

```
R> x <- read.table(textConnection("
X Y
1 1
1 4
2 7"), header=TRUE)

R> y <- read.table(textConnection("
X Y Z
1 1 24
1 2 30
1 4 15
2 2 40
2 5 10
2 7 12"), header=TRUE)

R> merge(x, y, all=FALSE)
  X Y  Z
1 1 1 24
2 1 4 15
3 2 7 12
```

Comment: The "all=FALSE" logical is what I was missing, Also thank you for formatting the my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
> file
  X Y  Z
1 1 1 24
2 1 2 30
3 1 4 15
4 2 2 40
5 2 5 10
6 2 7 12
> x
first second
1     1      1
2     1      4
3     2      7
> merge(x, file, by.x=x$first, by.y = file$X)
  first second  Z
1     1      1 24
2     1      4 15
3     2      7 12
```